# Format the current hour and minute using new Date() in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
var date = new Date();
let format = date.getFullYear()+'-'+(date.getMonth()+1)+'-'+date.getDate();
console.log(format); // result : 2021-10-28
```

Now I want to set it's hours and minutes as **00:00** and **23:59**. Example: **2021-10-28 00:00** and **2021-10-28 23:59**
,Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at https://date-fns.org/

Comment: You already have this format. The format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` for all three values.

Comment: @jabaa now I want instead of getting the current hour and minute, I want to set it to 00:00

Comment: That's not a different format. That's a different value. Because of the wrong wording a wrong duplicate was linked.

Comment: @jabaa Is there a simpler way to get the current date and time?

Comment: What you want is `date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);` and `date.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999);`

Comment: You can use string operations to add the time: `console.log(format + ' 00:00');` and `console.log(format + ' 23:59');`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the first and last minute of today?
You can use:

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date); // result: 2021-10-28 15:31

date.setHours(0);
date.setMinutes(0);
date.setSeconds(0);
console.log(date); // result: 2021-10-28 00:00

date.setHours(23);
date.setMinutes(59);
date.setSeconds(59);
console.log(date); // result: 2021-10-28 23:59
```